# HQL with a collection in the WHERE clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

I've been trying for the this whole a query who is officially giving me nightmares. The system is a user and contact management. So I have `UserAccount`, `Contact` and `Phone`.

`UserAccount` has a bidirectional one-to-many relationship with `Contact` and an unidirectional one on phone all mapped by a `Set`:

```
//UserAccount mapping 
@OneToMany(targetEntity=PhoneImpl.class, cascade= {CascadeType.ALL})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>();

@OneToMany(targetEntity=ContactImpl.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="userAccount")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
```

Contact now has a one-to-many unidirectional with phones

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=PhoneImpl.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>();
```

I'm writing a method to check the existence of the same number for the same contact of a particular user by the email unique field.

I know I could have overridden the `equals` and `hashcode` for that but since phone in a entity mapped by set I don't know at this moment how to do that. So I wanted to provide a method to rather check for that uniqueness for me before each entry on the contact page

```
public boolean checkForExistingPhone(String userEmail, String formatedNumber) {
    List<Contact> result = null;
    Session sess = getDBSession().getSession();

    String query = "select Contact ,cphones.formatedNumber from Contact c inner join    Contact.phones cphones where c.UserAccount.email = :email and cphones.formatedNumber= :number";
//        try {
        result = (List<Contact>) sess.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter("email", userEmail)
                .setParameter("number", formatedNumber).list();
//        } catch (HibernateException hibernateException) {
//            logger.error("Error while fetching contacts of email " + userEmail + " Details:"     + hibernateException.getMessage());
//        }
        if(result == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
}
```

I keep on having this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Contact is not mapped [select
cphones.formatedNumber from Contact c inner join Contact.phones cphones where
c.UserAccount.email = :email and cphones.formatedNumber= :number].
```

I can't really  figure out what happens and first i don't know how to treat collections in HSQ.thanks for reading

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HQL query would be probably something along these lines:

```
select c
from Contact c
join c.phones cphones
where c.userAccount.email = :email
  and cphones.formatedNumber = :number
```

Also you may want to handle results of query like this. The *list()* method returns always a list, never a null.

```
 return !result.isEmpty();
```

Comment: or `return !result.isEmpty();`
;)