# HQL query in query (find out collection in the second contains elements from the first)

Tags: sql, select, hql

I have 2 HQL queries below:

Suppose we have something like a vet clinic.

This is the first query:

```
SELECT cat FROM Animal cat WHERE case_id = \'cat\' AND cat.registrationDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

The query above is pretty straightforward, we get all animals which are of subtype "cat" and registered at particular time.

The second query is below:

```
SELECT vet FROM Veterinarian vet WHERE vet.treatedAnimals /*cointains at least one element from the first query (of the type "cat")*/
```

In this query (which is mocked) I'm trying to get all vets which have treated ONLY cats from the first query. treatedAnimals is a collection which might or might not contain a cat (there also can be dogs, parrots, etc).

The thing here is that **case_id** is ambiguous (present in both tables, gives me an expection), so I can't use a plain **JOIN** here.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT vet FROM Veterinarian vet join vet.treatedAnimals animals WHERE animals.case_id = 'cat'
  MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT vet FROM Veterinarian vet join vet.treatedAnimals animals WHERE animals.case_id != 'cat'
```

NOTE:
1. Just to inspire, this statment is likely not correct in syntax.
2. This statement can be poor-performanced as it do redundant join and scan. Consider to improve your schema or look for non-SQL/HQL solution.

REFERENCE:
1. https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php
2. [HQL with a collection in the WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759610/hql-with-a-collection-in-the-where-clause)